# After git clone src folders appear to be just folder instead of packages in Eclipse ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse IDE with selenium, testng, Java on Ubuntu machine to automate test cases.
I committed a fresh new Project into Git and when on another machine by doing a git clone and importing the project. src folder which is source folder appears to be just a folder including the packages inside src folders.

How can i configure the project in such a way where after git clone and importing the project the src folders are intact and they appear to be src folders instead just folders.

Ecl;ispe IDE verison

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)
Build id: 20210612-2011
```

.Project content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>SeleniumTests</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

.classpath content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

It is a multi maven project

Comment: Why not current Eclipse? It might be caused by doing something wrong when importing the project, e.g. not choosing the right import function for your case or choosing the wrong directory. What and how did you import it exactly?

Comment: File -> Import -> Existing projects into workspace -> Next -> Select root directory -> Selected cloned folder -> Click finish

Comment: Well, that might be wrong, depending on what is in the Git repository. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please.

Comment: Were the `.project` and `.classpath` files committed into the repository from the original machine?

Comment: Yes .project and .classpath has been committed

Comment: Please add the content of `.classpath` and `.project` to you question.

Comment: Added both the contents

Comment: So it's a Maven project. Did you already update to Eclipse 2021-12? If not, do it now. Does right-clicking the project and choosing _Maven > Update Project..._ help? If not, tell whether errors are shown in the `pom.xml` and also show the content of it.